# How can I condense Edge bookmark styling?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I strongly dislike the "fat finger" look of the Edge bookmarks and prefer Chrome's condensed style. Is there a way to change this? I didn't see anything in settings.

**Edge v90.0.818.62**

[image: Edge Bookmarks]

**Chrome v90.0.4430.212**

[image: Chrome Bookmarks]

Comment: What version of Edge and what version of Chrome are you using exactly?  What add-ons in Chrome are you using if any?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound edited. I'm not using any extensions that affect the bookmarks. I removed the theme to confirm that's not affecting the bookmarks either.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior.  [Edge 90](edge://favorites/) and [Chrome 90](chrome://bookmarks/) look similar but also different for me (one has checkboxes the other doesn't).  On both pages it looks more like your Chrome then a compact list. I seem to recall Edge requesting if I wanted a compact look or not though when I first started it.